# Optimal Amazon EC2 server instance size/type for static content delivery via apache httpd

Tags: apache, configuration, static, amazon-ec2, scalability

**BACKGROUND:**

Building out an infrastructure for delivering high availability static web content via apache.  The traffic will definitely be sporadic, but could have high spikes on demand.

I plan on hosting all media/js/css on amazon cloudfront, while leaving all html to be delivered via apache on an Amazon EC2 instance.  I am using apache to deliver this content since I need to have sub-domain aliasing and this seemed like the easy solution, Otherwise I just would have used cloudfront to deliver the entire enchilada!  The instances will have nothing else running on them (Nothing Dynamic).  The EC2 instances will be load balanced using Amazon's Elastic Load Balancer and Auto Scaled to create new instances if necessary.

**THE QUESTIONS:**

Which instance type/size will give me optimal utilization of the instance resources for my dollar spent?  A little more generic and related question is, what aspects of an apache web server will get maxed out first and which metrics are the best indicator to have amazon add a new instance?

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using any programming language such as php or .net you can leave even your .html files in S3 and host the whole website from there. S3 has an option to turn your bucket into a website.

---

**Added extra info**

If using S3 is not an option then I recommend using the smallest server possible for your normal load. For example if normal load is 100 requests per second and you need a m1.small instance to handle the load then use that. If you need a c1.medium then use that as your instance size.

When your server is under a lot of load its recommended to use a load balancer and auto scaling. This lets you run `n * <server size>` servers running to handle the load you need. When the spike in traffic goes down it will automatically remove servers from the loadbalancer. The idea is that you only get charged for what you need. Don't run a c1.xlarge just because you need that for 2 hours during peak load.

The auto scaling can be triggered automatically based on a schedule if you know that you're going to have a spike in traffic due to advertising or it can be based on CPU usage, network utilization or some other metric.

Comment: Thanks bwight, but as noted above, I need some sub-domain aliasing magic via apache, so this is not an option.

Comment: I updated my answer to include some information if using S3 is not an option. Which it appears is not for you. I guess i missed that part of your post sorry.

Comment: No problem, I appreciate this suggestion. However, I was looking toward optimization more than scaling.  I understand that the auto scaling and load balancing will ramp everything up based on my X factor, but was hoping someone could answer the question of which instance will get the optimal utilization at maximum traffic levels for that instance.  I.E.  You can server 100 requests per second on a small instance or 1000 RPS on a medium high CPU instance....10 times the yield at double the price.  Anybody benchmarked these instance types with apache and small static content delivery?

Comment: Sorry I don't have any information on the comparison for hosting static files. Though generally speaking nginx is accepted as the faster web server for static files when compared to apache. That would be a good place to start, no matter what server you go with you're going to have a boost from the beginning.

Comment: Thanks bwight, I looked into apache vs nginx and apparently it cannot handle sub-domain aliasing, which I need.

Answer (score 0):

Having just moved a site to AWS, I would like to point out a slightly different direction you could consider. You want to serve up static files? **Let CloudFront do it for you**. The pricing on CloudFront is practically the same as transfer out of EC2, but you get 34 edge server locations on their global CDN and **your servers don't need to handle any requests at all**.

With the proper CNAME mapping on your DNS, you should be able to point various sub-domains to the any S3 bucket/folder you want on CloudFront. Now there is no need to worry as CloudFront/S3 with scale as big as you need. :)

P.S. CloudFront can also cache and serve up API request or cacheable pages if you fancy too!

Comment: I am running dynamic subdomains, based on user creation and don't see a direct solution for creating thousands of subdomains on the fly.

Comment: @ezwrighter As a rule, everything in AWS can be done in an API call, so you can batch up anything you like in large numbers. So, you can add your subdomains/S3 buckets to CF easily. However, you'll need to automate your subdomain w/ your registrar. Route53 can easily do this via the API if you use them for your DNS.

Comment: I don't use them for my DNS, and CloudFront caching in the past has been horrible to deal with.  If a user wants to make a change to their site, we could not force the old info stale and show the new.  Maybe if the caching issues have been resolved I will need to take a look.  Appreciate your feedback.

Comment: @ezwrighter True, I do not rely on CF cache invalidation. Instead, I simply rename all resources with hashes (images, css, js). This way only the entrypoint, such as index.html would need invalidation. But, if you set the cache headers for that file, index.html, to never cache that resource, then CF cache invalidation is not needed. FWIW, I use Google Web Toolkit, so it does all these renamings on compile automagically.